# valid delimiters used to separate key/value in properties file in java

Tags: java

Can anyone knows which are valid delimiters one can use for key/value pair, other than `=` to separate the key and value?
I tried `key:value` and worked, but i don't know it is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody uses `=`. `:` is the only other valid option, as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29).

Comment: Whitespace "in" a key must be escaped, so technically any whitespace counts as a delimiter between a key and a value. So be careful with properties which must have a space in the key.